# Number of unique people who don't own trucks, but own cars

Tags: relational-algebra

So, we have the tables:

```
Person (SIN, Name, Address, Owner_id)
Owner (Owner_id)
Vehicle (Vehicle_id, Plate_number)
Car (Vehicle_id, Cmodel, Cyear)
Truck (Vehicle_id, Tmodel, Tyear)
Owns (Owner_id, Vehicle_id)
```

How do I format a relational algebra statement so that I get the number of people who only own cars (not trucks)? We can assume that a Person might own more than one car, and we only want them to count for one person.

I don't even really know where to start with this question. I've been looking at it for a while and I'm very new to relational algebra, and having to potentially use all of these tables confuses me. Where do I start, and how do I extract the information to compare vehicle ownership?

Comment: Please don't delete questions after you've received a good answer.  Part of our mission here is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful not only to you but also to others in the future.  Answerers may have responded on that basis, so it might be considered impolite to delete your question after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get distinct car owners and do the [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Set_operators) with truck owners.

Use the table `Owns` as an intermediary to join the table `Person` and any of the tables `Car` or `Truck`.